# Virtualization is enabled on my host but VirtualBox shows it greyed out

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, windows, android-studio

I am running a Windows 10 host and a Ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual machine using VirtualBox.

I checked my Windows BIOS and it shows Intel Virtualization is Enabled.

[image: Windows Host Virtualization setting]

[image: VirtualBox setting Processor tab]

[image: VirtualBox setting Acceleration tab]

and so I get this in Android Studio on my Ubuntu host:

[image: Error in Android Studio on Ubuntu Host]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running VB 6.x? This thread should explain everything about nested virtualization (since you're trying to run a VM within a VM): https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=90831

Comment: 1. Use VMware or HyperV instead of VBox  or 2. Use AMD CPU with VBox.